# prevent further processing in child-class from super-class ( activity )

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-activity

I am searching for an elegant solution/pattern for this problem ( pseudo-code ):

```
public class LoggedInActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (!isUserLoggedIn()) {
         finish();
         startActivity(getLoginActivity());
        }
    }

    ...
}


class MainActivity extends LoggedInActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       codeThatShouldNotBeExecutedWithoutUser();
    }
}
```

I am searching for a way to not touch every child-class of LoggedInActivity and do a check there - In an Ideal world I can solve this problem in LoggedInActivity completely - but I do not see a way yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to solve this is:

1. Make `LoggedInActivity` an `abstract class`.
2. Add to it an abstract method:

   > abstract void codeThatShouldNotBeExecutedWithoutUser();
3. Change all subclasses to implement (and override) `codeThatShouldNotBeExecutedWithoutUser()`. If they already implement that method, you should at least add the `@Override` annotation to make it clear that the method is being overridden.
4. Remove the calls to `codeThatShouldNotBeExecutedWithoutUser()` from all the subclasses.
5. Change `LoggedInActivity.onCreate()` to call `codeThatShouldNotBeExecutedWithoutUser()` if and only if the user is logged in:

   > ```
   > @Override
   > protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   >     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   >     if (!isUserLoggedIn()) {
   >        finish();
   >        startActivity(getLoginActivity());
   >     } else {
   >        codeThatShouldNotBeExecutedWithoutUser();
   >     }
   > }
   > ```

Comment: thanks - but that still would mean I have to touch all child - activities

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I presume every subclass needs to have its own implementation of `codeThatShouldNotBeExecutedWithoutUser()`. The main change would be too remove the call to  `codeThatShouldNotBeExecutedWithoutUser` from the subclasses, which is what I understood you wanted?

Comment: codeThatShouldNotBeExecutedWithoutUser() was just pseudo-code and is different code in every child class - so I would have to touch all child classes to introduce this function

Comment: That is basically what I said as well. So I am still not clear what you are really trying to do. Are you actually trying to avoid changing the subclasses for some reason? If so, then please clarify what the current implementations of the subclasses and base class look like. For instance, is every subclass already calling its own implementation of that method?

Comment: Why don't you want top change the subclasses, are there dozens of them or something?

Comment: I just searched for a more elegant solution - but this seems to be it for now - thanks anyway!